# iOS Core Data <fault after searching

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

All, I am having problems with Core Data.

I have a method that queries all data which matches a jobId

```
- (JobSummary*)summaryForJobId:(NSInteger)jobId {
    NSFetchRequest* request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:[JobSummary entityName]];
    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"jobId = %D", jobId];

    JobSummary* summary = [[self.context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil] lastObject];

    NSLog(@"DB Summary: %@", summary);

    [request setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];

    return summary;
}
```

When called and I log out it works perfect, however when I call it from a seperate view controller like so;

```
JobSummary *retrievedDictionary = [[FSScheduleDatabaseTransaction new] summaryForJobId:jobid];
```

When I log out retrievedDictionary it spits out this;

```
<JobSummary: 0x12de24a0> (entity: JobSummary; id: 0xb3c19b0 <x-coredata://7E9F6C6E-B4A0-4450-8905-184C6C8FB60D/JobSummary/p169> ; data: <fault>)
```

**Any help much appreciated!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is giving you the log correctly. When ever you try to print the `ManagedObject` you'll only see a `fault` in logs.

> A fault is a placeholder object that represents a managed object that has not yet been fully realized, or a collection object that represents a relationship:
>
> - A managed object fault is an instance of the appropriate class, but its persistent variables are not yet initialized.
> - A relationship fault is a subclass of the collection class that represents the relationship.

So, in short, unless you try to access those properties, CoreData wont fill property values. It will have a `fault`. Just trying to log the `ManagedObject`, without accessing its properties previously, will only show `fault`.